# Unable to use a struct that uses a template as a parameter in a method

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct TheStruct {
    A a;
    B b;
};

class TheClass {
public:
    void do_something(TheStruct<A,B> blah);
}
```

I get compiler errors on the `do_somethng` method that resembles `error: 'A' was not declared in this scope`...

What is the correct syntax for defining this kind of type in a method parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: What are A and B in `TheClass`?

Comment: I was assuming they are the same as A and B in TheStruct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to either make `TheClass` a template:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class TheClass {
public:
    void do_something(TheStruct<A,B> blah);
};
```

Or you'll need to make `do_something()` a template:

```
class TheClass {
public:
    template <typename A, typename B>
    void do_something(TheStruct<A,B> blah);
};
```

Comment: @TonyK:  What's not true?  Isn't it fairly obvious that the OP wants `do_something` to operate generically?

Comment: This looks true to me...  It's definitely a solution, the question doesn't make it clear whether the we want to propogate the generic A and B parameters to also be generic in TheClass, but I'd say it's a pretty reasonable assumption.

Comment: I see now what the OP was looking for. Err...how do I remove my downvote?

Comment: @TonyK: click on the down arrow again (it's a toggle switch).

Comment: @TonyK: Click on the down arrow again.  But I think I need to make a change to it first. (I changed a period to a colon)  If you can't, don't worry, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A and B are just placeholders in the template definition. To make this clear: your template definition is semantically the same as

```
template <typename TotallyDifferentA, typename TotallyDifferentB>
struct TheStruct {
    TotallyDifferentA a;
    TotallyDifferentB b;
};
```

So it's not surprising that

```
void do_something(TheStruct<A,B> blah);
```

doesn't compile. A and B are not defined. This compiles:

```
class TheClass {
public:
    void do_something(TheStruct<int,void(*)(double,char*)> blah);
} ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification...so explain why PigBen's answer is invalid if he's simply defining another template that just so happens to have the same typenames (A & B).  Ultimately, I don't want to pass any non-template types (int, void(*)(double,char*) to the do_something...

Comment: OK, now I see what you wanted :-)

Answer (score 0):

That depends. Do you want `do_something` to work on ANY version of `TheStruct`, or one specific one (for example where type `A` is `int` and `B` is `double`?

For the first case you'll need to make either `TheClass` or `do_something` ALSO a template (example grabbed from @PigBen):

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class TheClass {
public:
    void do_something(TheStruct<A,B> blah);
};
```

OR

```
class TheClass {
public:
    template <typename A, typename B>
    void do_something(TheStruct<A,B> blah);
};
```

If you just need to work with one specific instantiation of `TheStruct` then you specify the exact types:

```
class TheClass {
public:
    void do_something(TheStruct<int, double> blah);
}
```